# Impala SQL, return value if a string exists within a subset of values

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table where the `id` field (not a primary key) contains either `1` or `null`.  Over the past several years, any given part could have been entered multiple times with one, or both of these possible options.

I'm trying to write a statement that will return some value if there is ever a `1` associated with the select statement.  There are lots of semi-duplicate rows, some with `1` and some with `null`, but if there is ever a `1`, I want to return `true`, and if there are only `null` values, I want to return `false`.  I'm not sure how to code this though.

If this is my `SELECT part,id from table where part = "ABC1234"` statement

```
part      id
ABC1234   1
ABC1234   null
ABC1234   null
ABC1234   null
ABC1234   1
```

I want to write a statement that returns `true`, because `1` exists in **at least one of these rows.**

The closest I've come to this is by using a `CASE` statement, but I'm not quite there yet:

```
SELECT
a1.part part,  
CASE WHEN a2.id is not null             
  THEN
        'true'
  ELSE
        'false'
  END AS            id
from table.parts a1, table.ids a2 where a1.part = "ABC1234" and a1.key = a2.key;
```

I also tried the following case:

```
CASE WHEN exists
       (SELECT id from table.ids where id = 1)               
  THEN
```

but I got the error `subqueries are not supported in the select list`

For the above `SELECT` statement, how do I return 1 single line that reads:

```
part      id
ABC1234   true
```

Comment: how is this related to `mysql` ? Tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to check if a part has atleast one row with id=1.

```
SELECT part,'True' id
from parts
group by part
having count(case when id = 1 then 1 end) >= 1
```

To return false when the id's are all nulls use

```
select part, case when id_true>=1 then 'True'
                  when id_false>=1 and id_true=0 then 'False' end id
from (
SELECT part,
count(case when id = 1 then 1 end) id_true,
count(case when id is null then 1 end) id_false,
from parts
group by part) t
```

Comment: Won't this *only* return rows where there is ever a value of `1` in the id column?  If a value exists where there is no `1` ever, it won't be returned as `false` - unless I'm misunderstanding your SQL.

Comment: @BrianPowell .. i just saw you needed to return false as well and edited the answer.